# Why is it hard to concentrate on Kusala?

Tags: personal-practice, mindfulness, right-mindfulness

When I try to concentrate when studying, I end up with a wandering mind, but when I'm watching a video, I forget all the other things. Why is it hard to focus on things I really need? Is it some kind of practise? This was a lot easier to do for Lord Buddha, Ven. Arahant Moggollana.

Is focusing on Akusala than Kusala in samsara the problem? Do I have to build up practise of focusing to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

If we were completely separate from the world, completely independent - then the perfect focus on virtue would be easy.

But we are not separate, not isolated. We are connected with people and events around us. We are part of the web of influences.

These influence create context for our existence. Our desires and decisions come from this context. A lot of time we are carried away by these impulses, despite our best intentions.

The easiest thing we can do to overcome this is to choose which influences we expose ourselves to. Move to kusala city, make kusala friends, watch kusala movies etc. Surround yourself with kusala and it will be easier to focus on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, kusala is against the natural instinctual stream of akusala

For example, if you a hetero man, you see a sexy lady and very quickly sensual desire arises immediately, without any thinking about the lady. this is natural instinct

The suttas explain there are [seven underlying tendencies](https://suttacentral.net/an7.11/en/sujato) in people; the 1st and most powerful is the tendency to sensual lust (kāmarāga)

The suttas explain there are [five hindrances](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.38/en/sujato) to concentration; the 1st and most powerful is the hindrance of sensual desire (kāmacchando)

Watching a video is an example of sensual desire.

You overcome it by thinking deeply about the harm of it. For example, if you do not study, you do not get an education, you get a poor job, you make little money, and no sexy ladies want to marry you because you are poor and just watch videos